# How to display inbox messages based on which user is logged in?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a website which is developed in ASP.NET. One of the page requires to display messages which are stored in a database. Currently I can retrieve these message and show them on the page without a problem using `<asp:Gridview>`. My problem is that every message is displayed to all the users. For example;

**User 1 can see "bla bla"**

**User 2 can see "bla bla"**

I want to somehow manage to show each message based on which user is logged in. For Example;

**User 1 can only see ABC**

**User 2 can only see DEF**

The below code is used on the Inbox page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Message2" HeaderText="Message" HeaderStyle-Width="150" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SentDate" HeaderText="Sent Date" HeaderStyle-Width="150" />
             </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I retrieve the messages from the Data at the `Page_Load` function.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Message2,SentDate FROM Messages"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    this.GridView1.Attributes.Add("bordercolor", "#e9e9e9");
}
```

I am really stuck on this so any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: In this case you need to fetch userId of the user who has logged in and fetch messages for that userId only. For this you need to have relation between the Message and the user inside the Table you are using to fetch the messages from. So your Query will look like "SELECT Message2,SentDate FROM Messages where UserId = @userid"

Comment: What you're looking for is a `WHERE` clause in your SQL statement.  You'd add that clause with a parameter to hold the value, and the value you supply it is whatever you use to filter the users (user id, user name, etc.).

Comment: @KrunalPatil Thanks, make more sense now

Answer (score 0):

Add the User Information in the Message Table

```
 create table Messages (User varchar(30),Message2 Varchar(100),
        SentDate Varchar(100));
```

And to retrieve the information for each user modify the SQL query by including where clause.

```
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Message2,SentDate FROM 
        Messages where User="+user.toString()));
```